# Assertion debug type independent?

Tags: objective-c, c

I have written my own assertion debug.

```
#define ASSERT_EQUALS(a,b) \
do { \
    if ((a)!=(b)) \
    { \
        printf(". ASSERT_EQUALS (%s:%d) %d!=%d\n",__FUNCTION__,__LINE__,a,b); \
    } \
} while (0)
```

However its only compatible with integer types. Is there a way I can change this so I can support float/double types as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Its C. Can't Answer it shortly than that. C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should just print them as floats.

```
#define ASSERT_EQUALS(a, b) \
  do { \
    if ((a)!=(b)) { \
      printf(". ASSERT_EQUALS (%s:%d) %f!=%f\n",__FUNCTION__,__LINE__,(float)(a),(float)(b)); \
    } \
  } while (0)
```

It looks bad with integers, for example `1` will show up as `1.00000`, but it will work for both types.

Comment: Just print them as they are ... it's a macro, after all, and the text of the arguments is available.

Answer (score 0):

Print them as strings; this works for all types and prints the actual text of the expressions, not just their values:

```
#define ASSERT_EQUALS(a,b) \
do { \
    if ((a)!=(b)) \
    { \
        printf(". ASSERT_EQUALS (%s:%d) %s!=%s\n",__FUNCTION__,__LINE__, #a,#b); \
    } \
} while (0)
```

Comment: This prints the actual text of the expressions *instead of* their values.  Surely the point of using a customised assertion macro here is to see more information?  With this implementation, `ASSERT_EQUALS(foo, bar)` isn't any more helpful than `assert(foo == bar)` -- in both cases, if the assertion fails, it tells you that `foo` and `bar` are not equal, without telling you what the values actually are!

Comment: I'm not sure what the OP's point of using a customized assertion macro is, but the general point of such a macro is to identify a failure. Fixing the failure is going to require debugging. and  knowing more than just the values of a and b. But if that's all the OP wants, and wants it to work for any numeric type including float and double, then casting the args to double seems very very obvious ... I provided something that isn't so obvious, I think.

Answer (score -1):

Use a variadic macro and vprintf.  Look at the assert.h in your C library

Comment: You would still need to know the types and thus what format to use. There's a better approach for macros, where the actual text of the arguments is available; see my answer.

Comment: P.S. Looking at assert.h is a good idea ... a pity that you didn't! It uses stringization, not vprintf.

Comment: READ CLOSELY: assert takes one expression argument; it is not a varargs macro; it has no reason to call vfprintf, and doesn't. See, I actually did look at the assert.h in my C library, from gcc -- not that I needed to, having been a libc developer and a member of X3J11. In most implementations, the assert macro invokes a function, called  __assert or something similar. __assert, not being a varargs function, has no reason to call vfprintf ... but even if it did, one wouldn't know that by reading assert.h. AND as I noted in my first comment, vfprintf DOESN'T HELP here.